# Paying Extra Rents

Tags: monopoly

Somebody (who was also the banker) just landed on my Vine street with a hotel on it and needed to pay me $1000. However, he gave me an extra $100 bill, which both of us did not notice.

Two other players rolled the dice and took their turns.

After I also took my turn, I started to develop my Yellow group with 7 houses (I had $27 left at the end of the process) and the person who landed on my hotel found out that I had $100 more than I should have had, while he was $100 short. He demanded his money back and that meant I had to sell the houses to pay the "debt".

According to the rules, do I have to?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Monopoly specifically but most games have a "dice rolled" policy where once the dice roll everything prior is set in stone. In a tournament, someone may receive a warning, and consistent warnings lead you disqualified. Out of a tournament, you just lose friends and they won't play with you. Again, this is general and I'm not familiar with the intricacies of Monopoly specifically,

Comment: Just noticed this was closed as "opinion based" however it is standard game policy (and common sense) that if a mistake is not caught before the next player starts their turn than it is too late to call them out on it. If the rules of Monopoly do not specifically state what to do then, like common law, that standard would apply.  Of course the players can negotiate a settlement if they want, but there is no obligation to. The fact here that TWO other players took their turn... there can be no reasonable way to say NOW fix it! Not opinion, but historical gaming tradition fact.

Answer (score 3):

No you absolutely should not have had to sell the house back in order to pay the extra 100 back to the other player. At worst you should have have undone the transaction so that you had enough money to return the extra 100. I say this because having to sell the houses punishes you as you would end up with less money and 2 fewer houses purchased with the sell back instead of just 1 fewer house with the correct rent given.

The question I would have to ask overall is why was this noticed after you had made your hotel purchases? Could this have been done to put you at a disadvantage as a result of purchasing houses that may have hurt that player? Unless your opponent was a younger player I would think that counting out the correct amount of rent isn't difficult especially when the over payment sounds like it was an extra bill added in.

In the long run there is an iron clad rule I try to stick to in games and that is if a mistake is made and not noticed until later it is allowed to stand as it can be extremely complicated unwind everything to undo it at a later time. The only time this isn't the case is when the mistake would mean forfeiting the game itself. The biggest reasoning for letting mistakes stand is it helps reinforce the need to better pay attention to the game and rules which helps improve how the game is played and make it more enjoyable for everyone.

Comment: " if a mistake is made and not noticed until later it is allowed to stand " <- this! Pretty standard policy across many games.

Comment: @RebusB  I've never played with people who wouldn't try and undo an honest mistake.  There is no way that allowing cheating is standard policy.  In this case its incredibly easy to rectify and should be done as soon as noticed.

Comment: @StartPlayer - its not cheating. It is a mistake that was missed and play continued. After another turn has been taken there may be no way to undo the previous mistake without breaking the game. Unless you are recording each play it would be easy to forget something. So the only fair thing is to accept the mistake and move on. If it was done on purpose, as a cheat, then its up to the other players to catch it in time. If _they_ miss it that is on them, and they better pay more attention from then on.

Comment: @StartPlayer - For example in Backgammon if you see the opponent has counted wrong you can call them out on it as soon as he finishes his turn. But once you throw the dice for your turn that opportunity has passed, those are the rules...

Comment: @StartPlayer It isn't about being unwilling to undo an honest mistake but the question about what kind of impact undoing that mistake would have. In this case if undoing the mistake meant selling back houses the player that received the extra money would lose more in the long run as you only get half of the purchase price when selling them back. While it may not have been so in this case undoing a mistake could cause an unrelated player impact as well such causing them to lose or preventing a win. What I have found is it is best to learn from these mistakes and prevent them in the future.

Comment: Basically as that guy was the banker he was wondering why I had so much money to buy the houses because I had very little money at first. Then, he found out he had $100 less after counting HIS money.

Answer (score -7):

Absolutely - because you were aware at the time and refused to give proper change for the amount tendered.

If this was a dispute about the facts, time has expired - but this is about attempting to correct a blatant cheat on your part, and if you will not remedy I would fully expect you to be ejected from the game as a cheat, and not invited back again.

Comment: Do I need to tell you to look at the question again? I said that "both of us were not aware" until the next turn when the guy who paid me extra knew something was wrong.